# How to find the size of a deep learning model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, quantization

I am working with different quantized implementations of the same model, the main difference being the precision of the weights, biases, and activations. So I'd like to know how I can find the difference between the size of a model in MBs that's in say 32-bit floating point, and one that's in int8. I have the models saved in .PTH format.

Comment: What about comparing the size of the pth files?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to calculate the number of parameters and buffers.
Then try to multiply them with the element size and you will have the size of all parameters.

```
model = models.resnet18()
param_size = 0
buffer_size = 0
for param in model.parameters():
    param_size += param.nelement() * param.element_size()

for buffer in model.buffers():
    buffer_size += buffer.nelement() * buffer.element_size()

size_all_mb = (param_size + buffer_size) / 1024**2
print('Size: {:.3f} MB'.format(size_all_mb))
```

And it will print:

> Size: 361.209 MB

Answer (score 1):

"To calculate the model size in bytes, one multiplies the number of parameters by the size of the chosen precision in bytes. For example, if we use the bfloat16 version of the BLOOM-176B model, we have 176*10**9 x 2 bytes = 352GB!"

This blog on HF would be worth the read: https://huggingface.co/blog/hf-bitsandbytes-integration

Answer (score 0):

Have written a small code to calculate the size of your model depending on the number of params your model has & `dtype` of your model
Currently supports `fp32`,`fp16` & `int8`

```
def cal_size(num_params,dtype):
    if dtype == "float32":
        return (num_params/1024**2) * 4
    elif dtype == "float16":
        return (num_params/1024**2) * 2
    elif dtype == "int8":
        return (num_params/1024**2) * 1
    else:
        return -1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import torchvision.models as models
    model = models.mobilenet_v2()
    #mobilenetv2 of width multiplier 1 has 3.4M params 
    total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
    model_size = cal_size(total_params,"float32")
    if model_size != -1:
        print("Size of model is :{:.2f} MB".format(model_size))
    else:
        print("Incorrect dtype")
```